# How can I access an inner Enum in Grails Test?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, enums, spock

I have a Groovy domain like this:

```groovy
package fantasy

    class Notification {

        enum NotificationType {
            INVITE_GENERAL, INVITE_CONTEST
        }

        NotificationType type

        String emailTo
        User toUser
        User fromUser
        String message
        boolean wasReadByToUser
        boolean wasReadByFromUser
        boolean fromUserRemoved

        Date dateCreated

        static constraints = {
            type(blank: false)
            toUser(nullable: true)
            emailTo(email: true, blank: false)
        }

        static mapping = {
            autoTimestamp true
        }
    }
```

And I need to access a notification type in a Grails.Groovy/Spock test...

How can I get at the Enum, as I've tried just about everything I can do. Here is my test so far:

```groovy
package fantasy

import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification

/**
 * See the API for {@link grails.test.mixin.domain.DomainClassUnitTestMixin} for usage instructions
 */
@TestFor(Notification)
@Mock([Notification, User])
class NotificationSpec extends Specification {


    // Notification
    Notification notification 

    // Fields
    String emailTo = "fmulder@fox.com"
    String message = "Trust No One"
    boolean wasReadByUser = false
    boolean wasReadByFromUser = false
    boolean fromUserRemoved = false

    // Date
    Date dateCreated

    // Mocks
    def toUser
    def fromUser

    def setup() {
        toUser = Mock(User)
        fromUser = Mock(User)
        dateCreated = new Date()

    }

    def cleanup() {
        toUser = null
        fromUser = null
        dateCreated = null
    }

    void "test valid entry will validate"() {
        setup:
        notification = new Notification(
            /* Here is where the problem is, see stacktrace below */
            type: Notification.NotificationType.INVITE_GENERAL,
            emailTo: "danaScully@fox.com",
            toUser: toUser,
            fromUser: fromUser,
            message: message,
            wasReadByUser: false,
            wasReadByFromUser: false,
            fromUserRemoved: false,
            dateCreated: dateCreated
        ).save(failOnError: false, flush: true)
        expect:
        Notification.count() == 1
        notification.validate()
    }

}
```

How can I access that inner Enum?

Here is the stackktrace I'm getting:

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.NativeEntryEntityPersister.persistEntity(NativeEntryEntityPersister.java:993)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.NativeEntryEntityPersister.persistEntity(NativeEntryEntityPersister.java:1138)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.EntityPersister.persist(EntityPersister.java:160)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.AbstractSession.persist(AbstractSession.java:522)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormInstanceApi.doSave(GormInstanceApi.groovy:194)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormInstanceApi.save_closure5(GormInstanceApi.groovy:162)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.DatastoreUtils.execute(DatastoreUtils.java:302)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.AbstractDatastoreApi.execute(AbstractDatastoreApi.groovy:37)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormInstanceApi.save(GormInstanceApi.groovy:161)
    at fantasy.NotificationSpec.test valid entry will validate(NotificationSpec.groovy:73)

Comment: I've also tried this:  <code>NotificationType type = NotificationType.INVITE_CONTEST</code>

Comment: What is the actual problem you are having, you mention in the test "Here is my issue", but is the issue that `type` is null, or it is not being set on the `Notification` constructor, or something else?

Comment: @mnd My problem is stated in the question. How can I access that inner enum in a test. What other info do you want. It's pretty clear.

Comment: When I used the classes you provided, I was able to set the type object, and retrieve it afterwards. I appreciate you adding the stack trace to provide more information, since the original question doesn't say where the access problem lies (if you can't access `NotificationType` on the `Notification` object, or if you can't access `INVITE_GENERAL` on the `NotificationType` object).

From the stack trace it looks like there is a problem with `save()` that needs to be addressed. Please change `failOnError` to `true` to help debug that issue. I recommend always using that flag in domain tests.